# Is there a way to use internal symbols in a Rust macro?

Tags: rust, rust-macros

Suppose my library defines`pub struct MyStruct { a: i32 }`. Then, suppose I define a procedural macro `my_macro!`. Perhaps I want `my_macro!(11)` to expand to `MyStruct { a: 11 }`. This proves that I must have used `my_macro!` to obtain `MyStruct`, since the `a` field is not public.

This is what I want to do:

lib.rs:

```
struct MyStruct {
    a: i32,
}

#[proc_macro]
pub fn my_macro(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let ast: syn::Expr = syn::parse(input).unwrap();
    impl_my_macro(ast)
}

fn impl_my_macro(expr: syn::Expr) -> TokenStream {
    let gen = match expr {
        syn::Expr::Lit(expr_lit) => match expr_lit.lit {
            syn::Lit::Int(lit_int) => {
                let value = lit_int.base10_parse::<i32>().unwrap();
                if value > 100 {
                    quote::quote! {
                        compile_error("Integer literal is too big.");
                    }
                } else {
                    quote::quote! {
                        MyStruct{a: #lit_int}
                    }
                }
            }
            _ => quote::quote! {
                compile_error!("Expected an integer literal.");
            },
        },
        _ => quote::quote! {
            compile_error!("Expected an integer literal.");
        },
    };
    gen.into()
}
```

And I would use it like this:

```
fn test_my_macro() {
    let my_struct = secret_macro::my_macro!(10);
}
```

But the compiler gives this warning:

```
error[E0422]: cannot find struct, variant or union type `MyStruct` in this scope
  --> tests/test.rs:14:21
   |
14 |     secret_macro::my_macro!(10);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope
```

Is it possible to achieve this in Rust?

Comment: If the usage of a macro is unavoidable, perhaps you want to wrap your macro with a function defined in your library (which would have access to `MyStruct`)?

Comment: From what I understand, this would prevent us from making the guarantee at compile time that `MyStruct` does not contain an `a` larger than 100. Using a function defeats the purpose. This is a contrived example, but I have a static guarantee that I want to enforce that requires checking code blocks. The check is simple, but getting a type at the end is hard.

Comment: Macros simply provide a shorthand for source code: once they have been expanded into the resulting tokenstream, they are treated just like code that was manually entered in full.  They cannot give access to items that are invisible from the call site; if you want to grant such access, then you will need to expose a public function that encapsulates the private behaviour.

Comment: As for the particular error (not "warning") you quote in your question, the reference to `MyStruct` in the macro expansion should be fully namespace-qualified (or else you must require callers to bring `MyStruct` into scope).  Unfortunately, creating fully namespace-qualified paths from a proc macro is a little tricky, as you don't know by what name crates are known at the call site: the most "correct" solution would be to have the caller provide a path to `MyStruct` in the invocation, although some proc macros just assume the crate will be known by its default name.